# 10th man drove to shul on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, minyan

If one of precisely ten men, who form a minyan, had driven to shul (the synagogue) on shabbat, is that an acceptable minyan?

I would have though not, since one is benefiting from his melacha on shabbat, but was told that either this is not called a benefit, or that one is allowed to benefit from melacha that is done by a Jew on shabbat in general, just not in the case of bishul.

Are either of those two things true?

Comment: I'd be willing to believe that it's not a benefit.  I wouldn't believe that you can benefit from melacha from a Jew on Shabbos.

Comment: This answer has all sorts of ramifications. For example (and from personal experience) - two small communities get together and rent a hall in a town halfway between the two communities so they can hold High Holiday services. This is about the only remaining link to orthodox prayer that they have and if the link is lost.... Is it permissible for someone to go there (takes own food, in local hotel etc.) to conduct their services?

Comment: @Epicentre, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your contribution here, which I've converted to a comment.  I look forward to your participation here.

Comment: @Epicentre That sounds like a [separate question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can't benefit from a melacha done by a Jew on Shabbos, not just bishul. Bishul is just the common, obvious example (see [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935206/jewish/Chapter-Six.htm) for a source I could find online - where many different types of Malacha are a problem. It is talking about a non-Jew, but it is certainly not less for a Jew).

My first reaction is "[מצות לאו להנות ניתנו](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95_%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95)" - Mitzvos are not given for benefit, so something which is forbidden to derive benefit from can still be used for a Mitzvah. Especially in this context, where the benefit is indirectly from the work (it is not a product of the work, like bishul, in the direct sense - like @Shalom alludes to). But it could entirely be about the benefit being indirect.

Comment: so if a Jew turns the lights on in a room on Friday night should I not go in to that room because I benefit from the light?

Comment: @Dan, see here: http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=191&article=665

Comment: What about about מומר לחלל שבת? Is he good for use in a minyan?

Comment: @Shokhet [Maybe](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/halacha/din-2.htm), according to the Chazon Ish anyway. Certainly an angle that a Psak would have to consider, unlike a Mi.Yodea answer which is focus on the premise and angle of the question.

Comment: @Yishai Fair enough. Where on that page did you see that opinion of חזון איש? ....a quick search showed that his name only came up in connection with יין נסך and יבום.....

Comment: @Shokhet, it doesn't directly discuss Minyan, but the point being if he is not a מומר then he just isn't. Maybe. יין נסך is לקולא so it is more relevant that יבום.

Comment: @Yishai Interesting answer, but I don't know what "derive benefit" [i.e., from a melacha] could possibly mean if it didn't include filling out a minyan. I think they intend the words "derive benefit" as broadly as possible, to encompass any type of collateral reward we could glean from the prohibited action. This would include the ability to complete a minyan. ("Melacha for the sake of a mitzvo" is a separate issue, IMO...)

Comment: @SAH, hearing Shofar is the classic example. You can hear Shofar from a Shofar that you cannot derive benefit from (say because of a neder). Sure you derive benefit - a Mitzvah. But because the benefit is a Mitzvah, Mitzvas are not for "benefit" and as such don't fall under the prohibition.

Comment: @Yishai I'm going to give you the bounty, but I'd be grateful if you could help me with this subtle question: Sure, the *mitzvah* isn't for benefit--but surely it's a "benefit" to have something that facilitates doing the mitzvah?

Comment: @SAH, thanks for the bounty. Do you mean possession? As in just owning it?

Comment: @SAH, I'd like to answer your question, but I'm just not clear on what it is. What do you mean by a benefit "to have something that facilitates"? Do you mean owning something that facilitates?

Answer (score 1):

Cooking is a case where the food is a direct physical result of the prohibited action. Don't eat that food on shabbos.

Okay this fellow happened to have driven himself here, but he could have gotten here on foot or in a wheelchair (assuming eruv); I don't think counting him in for a minyan is the same type of tangible benefit from the direct result of prohibited labor.

A more interesting question: if I open a synagogue someplace where I know most people will drive, am I facilitating that? Rabbi Rakeffet discusses it and mentions the psak he's heard: if there are ten people within a two mile radius then it's conceivable to have a minyan without anyone driving, therefore it's permissible to open the synagogue.

Comment: What do you do if one of them goes away for shabbat?

Comment: what if he couldn't have gotten there on foot.

Comment: And I thought that food is asur b'hana'ah?

Comment: @soandos - you go by rov.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin see above

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I go by rov for what? If you mean that I go by rov with regard to the number of times, I would argue that it is not relevant. On a particular, known shabbat, it is a fact that there is no way that there will be ten shomer shabbat people that can get there. Why should there be minyan that shabbat then?

Comment: not to be overly PC, but I don't think you mean "ten people" unless you count animists and ten-year-olds in your minyan.

Comment: @soandos yes, that's what i mean.  Why is that not relevant?  Most shabboses, you expect most people to be home.  So any given shabbos you may not have a minyan of walkers, but it's not impermissible to make a shul there.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I mean lets say the shul is there already. On a certain shabbat you know you will not have a minyan of walkers. How can you justify, for that shabbat only, having minyan?

Comment: @soandos I was answering the question you raised in response to Shalom's answer (permissibility of building a shul if one person goes away), not the original question.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, sorry, I misunderstood